# Racket: Difference between `range` and `in-range`

Tags: for-loop, functional-programming, racket, sequence

There are two possibilities to generate a sequence of numbers to be iterated in a *for* loop in *Racket*:

```
(for ([i (range 1 5)])
    (display i))
```

and

```
(for ([i (in-range 1 5)])
    (display i))
```

`range` and `in-range` both work and seem to be equivalent, but https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html says:

> "An in-range application can provide better performance for number
> iteration when it appears directly in a for clause."

Does this also hold true in comparison to `range`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `range` is equally performant as `in-range` when it syntactically appears directly in `for` clauses. In fact, `range` is simply [transformed](https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/848d2a5db2f7523ea6d9d7c4d3a3a18485dd59a7/racket/collects/racket/list.rkt#L572) to `in-range` in that case.

Note that while it's true that `range` and `in-range` are functionally equivalent when they appear in `for` clauses, they are not functionally equivalent in general.

```
> (range 5)
'(0 1 2 3 4)
> (in-range 5)
#<stream>
```